# Django - serving an Angular app

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular

I'm trying to integrate Angular and Django and I am encountering a problem when I point to the index.html in the angular folder.

My url pattern in djangoapp.urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^.*/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

Which successfully opens the index.html template in my angular app. However, the angular app isn't able to reach the app.component.html and deliver content. I just get a blank page (index.html, which displays nothing atm) when i visit 127.0.0.1:8000/anything.

If I cd into angular app directory and ng serve --open and visit 127.0.0.1:4200 I get the regular front page you would get with app.component.html in the mix (The angular welcome page). The templates are the standard ng new templates, index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularWebapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get django to let my angular app access it's child-pages?

Comment: You need to build the angular project (`ng build`), and point at the `index.html` in the `dist` directory that is created

Comment: I ran ng-build, got a dist folder with a sub-folder with the apps name, inside that was index.html which i pointed djangos template dirs to and it loaded. However, it's still the same as before, a blank page that doesn't contact app.components.html correctly, any advice?